# Install an iPhone app for testing without the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am a new iPhone developer and I have an app that I want to install on a tester's phone. This is to test before it gets submitted to the app store. I won't have access to the physical phone. I want to send them a package to install. First, is this possible? If so, what is the best way to go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com) service.

Answer (score 4):

The following services is used to Test the Beta Testing in Mobile Applications.

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/) - beta distribution of iOS apps (Not used jailbroken devices).

[knappsack](http://knappsack.com/) - It allows air installation of your apps

[hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/) - It work All Platforms Except Blackberry

[appblade](https://appblade.com/) - supports all three of the platforms you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate an IPA file (Build and Archive / share) and send it to your tester. He will be able to install it to his device using Itunes.

If his device is not jailbroken then you will need to add his UDID to the mobile provisioning you are using to sign the application.

If you need more detail about anything, I will expand this answer.
Good luck!

Comment: I will definitely be able to use this option.  Thanks.